# CakePhP association not displaying as expected

Tags: cakephp, model, associations

I am new to Cakephp and I am having trouble with the following association.  What I am after is listing Parts in a table, along with their associated Source vendor.  So in the View/index.ctp the table I am currently getting is

```
ID    Source     Part #
1       1        Part00001
```

but I would like the association to display

```
ID    Source     Part #
1     Vendor 1   Part00001
```

where the Source.name is from the mstr_sources db table, not the mstr_parts table.
Below are snippets from all the pertinent code

```
class MstrPart extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'MstrPart';
    public $belongsTo = 'MstrSource';
}

class MstrPartsController extends AppController {
    public function index() {
        $this->set('parts', $this->paginate());
    }
}

// <!-- File: /app/View/Users/index.ctp -->
<?php foreach ($parts as $part): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $part['MstrPart']['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $part['MstrPart']['mstr_source_id']['name']; ?></td>
    //Also tried the following, still fails
    //<td><?php echo $part['MstrPart']['MstrSource']['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $part['MstrPart']['name']; ?></td>
</tr>

//  Output of the error message context.
$viewFile = 'C:\Dev\UniServerZ\www\campman\app\View\MstrParts\index.ctp'
$dataForView = array(
    'parts' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'MstrPart' => array(
                [maximum depth reached]
            ),
            'MstrSource' => array(
                [maximum depth reached]
            )
        )
    )
)
$parts = array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'MstrPart' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'mstr_source_id' => '1',
        'created' => '2013-12-18 16:10:35',
        'modified' => '2013-12-18 16:10:35',
        'name' => 'Part00001',
        'description' => 'Just some basic text, not the real thing.'
        ),
        'MstrSource' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'created' => '2013-12-19 12:23:22',
            'modified' => '2013-12-19 12:23:22',
            'name' => 'Vendor 1'
        )
    )
)
$part = array(
    'MstrPart' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'mstr_source_id' => '1',
        'created' => '2013-12-18 16:10:35',
        'modified' => '2013-12-18 16:10:35',
        'name' => 'Part00001',
        'description' => 'Just some basic text, not the real thing.'
    ),
    'MstrSource' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'created' => '2013-12-19 12:23:22',
        'modified' => '2013-12-19 12:23:22',
        'name' => 'Vendor 1'
    )
)
include - APP\View\MstrParts\index.ctp, line 35
View::_evaluate() - CORE\Cake\View\View.php, line 929
View::_render() - CORE\Cake\View\View.php, line 891
View::render() - CORE\Cake\View\View.php, line 460
Controller::render() - CORE\Cake\Controller\Controller.php, line 952
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 192
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 160
[main] - APP\webroot\index.php, line 108
```

Is there something obvious that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would just need to change this line

```
<td><?php echo $part['MstrPart']['mstr_source_id']['name']; ?></td>
```

To this

```
<td><?php echo $part['MstrSource']['name']; ?></td>
```

**EDIT:** I'll explain a bit.
In cakephp, all joined models (either joined via the 'join' tag within the `Model->find`, a containable behavior, or via the default bindings established in the model file) are included in the results array via a key of their model name. *it's their model name, not the table name. See [cakephp naming conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html) for more.

Since you want the column from `mstr_source` and not `mstr_part`, you want to reference the data inside the `MstrSource` dictionary and not `MstrPart`

Comment: Thanks, that's the fix.  Is that in the documentation anywhere that I may have overlooked?

Comment: Yeah you can read a little bit on this page. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-first
You're using a find('all'), but the structure of the data is described best in the section I linked to. It's confusing to get started, but you pick it up after some trial and error.